# Illegal Number Error - lowercase to uppercase conversion (0xdf)

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am using Tasm and been having this Illegal Number error when using and bl, 0xdf. I have tried adding '0' before the 'df' since according to others, this matters as well. Why do I get this error?

```
p1:
        mov ah, 2
        mov dl, 10
        int 21h
        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, d
        int 21h
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        mov bl, al

    p2:
        mov ah, 2
        mov dl, 10
        int 21h
        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, e
        int 21h
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        mov bh, al

    round:
        mov ah,2 
        and bl, 0xdf 
        cmp bl, 'R'
        je p1R
        cmp bl, 'P'
        je p1P
        cmp bl, 'S'
        je p1S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TASM is using the format `..h` for hexadecimal numbers, not `0x..`.

Write the constant as `0dfh`, similar to how you have written the other constants (like 21h).